# How to Send Email blog post to specific members in wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins, mailchimp

When I post an article in a wordpress blog and assign it to Specific category, is there a simple way to send the that post to specific group of members using ULTIMATE MEMBERSHIP PRO? For example, when I post an article and assign it to categories A,B and C...I want to automate a process to take the content of that blog post and send it via email to groups A, B and C within MAILING TOOLS.

I am certainly open to plugins that would achieve my goal. Actually, a well supported plugin would be my preference.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about a specific plugin but, you solve this using [`save_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/) hook.

```php
add_action( 'save_post', 'send_email_to_users', 10,3);
 
function send_email_to_users( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    // Only want to set if this is a new post!
    if ( $update ){
        return;
    }
     
    // Only set for post_type = post!
    if ( 'post' !== $post->post_type ) {
        return;
    }

    // if (<already_sent> == true) { return; } 
     
   // Check if the post has the categories A, B, C.

   // Mail users about the blog.

   // create a custom field to record, if you have sent them email.

}
```